# Passing id from element via ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, events

I'm constructing quite a big `<span>` - element that is being generated dynamically in code.

```
var span = '<span id="' + dayNumber + '/' + Number(currentMonth + 1) + "/" + Number(date.getFullYear()) + '" class="day ' + respons[0] + '" ng-click="gotoDetail($event)" style="height:' + screenHeigt + 'px; display:table;"><p style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">' + dayNumber + ' </p></span>';
```

As you can see, the id consist of a date-string. Via the ng-click-element I would like to pass the id to the gotoDetail($event)-function. When I'm inspecting the parameter of that function, I see however that `$event.target.id` is empty...

Following code is an older version and does work:

```
var span = '<span id="' + dayNumber + '/' + currentMonth + '" class="day ' + respons[0] + ' ' + lastMonth + ' " ng-click="gotoDetail($event)">' + dayNumber + '</span>' + string;
```

I really don't  know what I'm doing wrong in the first example...
If I check my html in the chrome-console, there's nothing wrong with the id, the ng-click, or other attributes...

Someone who has an anwser?

EDIT: Code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c29798e0d46f40dcfe69

Comment: Can you reproduce in Fiddle ?

Comment: Well, definitely you have changed something else. Do you still use `$compile` to insert your newly constructed element?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm using compile... I'm going to make a JSFiddle as soon as I can.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c29798e0d46f40dcfe69

I can't execute any JsFiddle or Codepen, but here is my code.